# List process by name excluding grep

Tags: linux, grep, process, ps

I am trying to list all the `ffmpeg` processes that are currently running on Debian machine (Ubuntu 15).

I use the following command:

```
ps aux | grep 'ffmpeg'
```

If only one `ffmpeg` process is running, I still get two results. One for the actual process, and one for `grep` that is looking for `ffmpeg` in the process list.

```
max      21599 13.2  3.0 503848 92288 ?        Rl   01:39   1:18 ffmpeg -f video4linux2 -i /dev/video0 -f mpeg1video -b:v 800k -r 30 http://127.0.0.1:8082/oops/1024/640/ -nostdin -nostats -loglevel fatal
max      23789  0.0  0.0  13688  2172 pts/3    S+   01:49   0:00 grep --color=auto ffmpeg
```

How can I modify my request so that the grep result which is actually my request is omitted from the output?

Answer (score 4):

You can use a trick :

```
ps aux | grep '[f]fmpeg'
```

Here `[]` is a format used for indicating range of characters to match using `grep`, we are using `[f]` to match only `f`. As the `[f]` is converted into `f` already, the literal `ps aux | grep 'ffmpeg'` won't show up in `ps` output.

Also note that appearance of `ps aux | grep 'ffmpeg'` on the output of `ps aux | grep 'ffmpeg'` mainly depends on the time it takes for the process table to be shown.

Note that there is a program named `pgrep` to search for processes, you can us that if `ps aux` is not absolutely needed.